# Dojo: Select a tab on load depending on url parameter

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way to select a tab in a tab container upon load depending on a url parameter?

I have tried the following but nothing seems to happen and the tab I want is not selected:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
tabToSelect = getParameter("tab");
if(tabToSelect){
    dijit.byId("container").selectChild(tabToSelect); } }
```

I have console logged out the parameter and I know it is correct.

I have a strong feeling I am missing something....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that might have the same question, I got the answer off the dojo mailing list, have to pass the actual tab instead of just a string, as follows:

```
    var tab = tabToSelect && dijit.byId(tabToSelect);
    if(tab){ dijit.byId("container").selectChild(tab)};
```

Works like a charm now!